# FFMPEG: 2 FPS video to 30 FPS. How?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-editing, video-encoding

I have a 2 FPS video and I would like it to be a 30 FPS with a speed increase of 15. Is this "re-sampling up"? I don't even know how to google the question.

Comment: Which format? ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have solved my own problem. From [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video):

> Note that this method will drop frames to achieve the desired speed. You can avoid dropped frames by specifying a higher output frame rate than the input. For example, to go from an input of 4 FPS to one that is sped up to 4x that (16 FPS):
>
> `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -r 16 -filter:v "setpts=0.25*PTS" output.mkv`

I used this exact command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 30 -filter:v "setpts=PTS/15" output.mp4
```

And my 2 fps video became 30 fps with a 15x speed up factor. Cool!

I found some info on the -r option too [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143100/framerate-vs-r-vs-filter-fps):

> -r can be either an input or output option. As an input option, it retimes input frames at that rate. As an output option, it will duplicate or drop frames to achieve the given rate (note that it won't duplicate frames if output format accepts variable frame rate). Output r is the 'encoding rate' as well. If it is not specified, it is inherited from the input rate, whether that's manually set or altered or an inherent property of the stream.